# Problem when using a codeplex solution: SharePoint 2013 FBA Pack

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, forms-authentication

I could successfully deploy a codeplex solution allowing the management of SQL users for a web application where Form-based authentication has been activated (https://sharepoint2013fba.codeplex.com/), on a DEV and a TEST farm (DEV is a single server for web front end and application services) and TEST is a single web front end and a single application server.
Then we deployed the solution to our prod farm (2 web front ends and 2 application servers). Solution was deployed successfully, but when attempting to access any page of the solution (settings, user management,...) we get an error.

Below is the content of the log file for the error. I did some search on the web, and this kind of error is normally due to a problem with the solution. But in this case the solution works for our DEV and TEST farms. So I do not see what kind of problem our PROD environment has.

Thanks

```
02/02/2016 13:05:16.81     w3wp.exe (0x0F68)                           0x1080    SharePoint Foundation             Runtime                           tkau    Unexpected    System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "Resources.FBAPackWebPages.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "App_GlobalResources.5rkpwe2a" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.    at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.HandleResourceStreamMissing(String fileName)     at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Dictionary`2 localResourceSets, Boolean tryParents, Boolean createIfNotExists, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)     at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo requestedCulture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParent...    c3405b9d-3b6f-50e0-7247-5d9a3e1d16a9
02/02/2016 13:05:16.81*    w3wp.exe (0x0F68)                           0x1080    SharePoint Foundation             Runtime                           tkau    Unexpected    ...s, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)     at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)     at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String name, CultureInfo culture, Boolean wrapUnmanagedMemStream)     at System.Web.Compilation.ResourceExpressionBuilder.GetResourceObject(IResourceProvider resourceProvider, String resourceKey, CultureInfo culture, Type objType, String propName)     at Visigo.Sharepoint.FormsBasedAuthentication.MembershipSettings.get_MembershipApprovedEmail()     at Visigo.Sharepoint.FormsBasedAuthentication.FBASiteConfiguration.OnLoad(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesA...    c3405b9d-3b6f-50e0-7247-5d9a3e1d16a9
02/02/2016 13:05:16.81*    w3wp.exe (0x0F68)                           0x1080    SharePoint Foundation             Runtime                           tkau    Unexpected    ...fterAsyncPoint)    c3405b9d-3b6f-50e0-7247-5d9a3e1d16a9
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you have to make sure.

- solution deployed to all server correctly, check from central admin.
- Make sure you made changes to all the web.config files of following applications.

  - Web Applications on all web front end
  - Security token services on WFE
  - Central Admin Web.config
  - SharePoint 2013 must already be configured to use FBA. Instructions for configuring SharePoint 2013 to use FBA are here:
    http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/configuring-forms-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2013-part-1-creating-the-membership-database/